# Is any regular language L has infinite words?

Tags: regular-language, pumping-lemma

This is weird but by pumping lemma, say

> Let `L` be a regular language. There exists a constant `n` such that for every string `w` in `L` such that `|w| >= n`, we can break `w` in to `xyz` such that `xy*z` is also in `L`.

This lemma is strong because it argues for all regular languages. But what if the regular language `L = a`? There is only one word (`a`) in it. How the pumping lemma works for this case?

Comment: Nitpicking on types here -- `L = {a}` because a language is a set of strings.

Answer (score 0):

If `n = 2` then it is vacuously true that any `w` in `L` with `|w| >= n` satisfies the conclusion of the pumping lemma. No words in `L` are long enough to serve as counterexamples. More generally, if `L` is any finite language then `L` satisfies the pumping lemma: just take `n` to be greater than the length of the longest word in `L`.